# jQuery - finding last selected element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm learning jQuery from Head First series and working on one of their examples, I need to find the last selected element.

Here's what I have from Chapter 2: The page contains four images, when user clicks on them, they are offered a random discount message which appears at the bottom of each image. To make things look more interesting, I added the `slideUp()` function to the message which I learned Chapter 1 from the same book.

Here's how far I've come: When user clicks on one of the image, the random discount message slides down below it to show its message. When user clicks any other image, the earlier message slides back up and a new random discount message slides down below the clicked image. Here's a simplified version of my code.

```js
$('.jumpDiv').click(function () {
                $('.jumpDiv').children('.discountDiv').slideUp();
     $('.jumpDiv p').remove();
     var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
     var msg = '<p>Your discount is ' + discount + '%</p>';
     $(this).children('.discountDiv').append(msg);
     $(this).children('.discountDiv').slideDown();
});
```

```css
.jumpDiv{
    float:left;
}
#main{
    border:1px solid;
    height:500px;
    width:auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
 #main .jumpDiv{
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    height:245px;
    width:245px;
    font-size:20px;
}
#main .jumpDiv>div{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fee;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
.discountDiv{
    text-align: center;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<div id="main">
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

The  glitch I need to remove is, if user clicks on the same div repeatedly, the discount message div should stay as it is and just update the randomly generated content. How do I stop this div from sliding back up and down, if the user has clicked the same div again. Is there a way to access the last clicked element and somehow stop the discount message to slide back up before updating the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to store the reference to the `lastClicked` entity and compare it with the next clicked value, if it's same don't do anything. Take a look at the following.

```js
var lastClicked = null;
$('.jumpDiv').click(function () {
     if(lastClicked === this) {
         /*Don't do anything*/
         return;
     }

     $('.jumpDiv').children('.discountDiv').slideUp();
     $('.jumpDiv p').remove();
     var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
     var msg = '<p>Your discount is ' + discount + '%</p>';
     $(this).children('.discountDiv').append(msg);
     $(this).children('.discountDiv').slideDown();
    
     lastClicked = this;
});
```

```css
.jumpDiv{
    float:left;
}
#main{
    border:1px solid;
    height:500px;
    width:auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
 #main .jumpDiv{
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    height:245px;
    width:245px;
    font-size:20px;
}
#main .jumpDiv>div{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fee;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
.discountDiv{
    text-align: center;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<div id="main">
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks 11thdimension, I was thinking along the same lines, but cudn't figure out how to execute the idea...  Also, your solution has an even better and more appropriate version of what I originally planned... thanks a bunch....

Answer (score 2):

You can change the code to just `slideUp()` the visible `.discountDiv`, skipping if the element that was clicked already had one visible. You can use the jQuery selector [:visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) to do this test. Also you can skip the need to remove the `<p>` elements by just setting the html each time instead of appending.

```
$('.jumpDiv').click(function () {
  //Store these so you are not doing multiple selection calls.
  var jumpDiv = $(this);
  var discountDiv = jumpDiv.children('.discountDiv');

  var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
  var msg = '<p>Your discount is ' + discount + '%</p>';
  discountDiv.html(msg);

  //If element was not visible it means some other is and needs hiding
  if(!discountDiv.is(':visible')){
    //select all dicountDiv's that are currently visible and hide them
    $('.discountDiv:visible').slideUp();
  }
  discountDiv.slideDown();     
});
```

Demo

```js
$('.jumpDiv').click(function() {
  var jumpDiv = $(this);
  var discountDiv = jumpDiv.children('.discountDiv');
  var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
  var msg = '<p>Your discount is ' + discount + '%</p>';
  discountDiv.html(msg);
  if (!discountDiv.is(':visible')) {
    $('.discountDiv:visible').slideUp();
  }
  discountDiv.slideDown();
});
```

```css
.jumpDiv {
  float: left;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#main .jumpDiv {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  height: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#main .jumpDiv>div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.discountDiv {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've used a class to figure which one is open. Then test if the one we are about to close the same as the one we want to open, and only close it if that's not the same.

```js
$('.jumpDiv').click(function() {
  var activeDiscount = $('.discountDiv.active');
  if (activeDiscount.closest('.jumpDiv')[0] != $(this)[0]) {
    activeDiscount.removeClass('active').slideUp();
  }
  $('.jumpDiv p').remove();
  var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
  var msg = '<p>Your discount is ' + discount + '%</p>';
  $(this).children('.discountDiv').append(msg);
  $(this).children('.discountDiv').slideDown().addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.jumpDiv {
  float: left;
}

#main {
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 500px;
  width: auto;
  background-color: grey;
}

#main .jumpDiv {
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  height: 245px;
  width: 245px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#main .jumpDiv>div {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #fee;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.discountDiv {
  text-align: center;
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
  <div id="main">
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="jumpDiv">
      <div> Click Here</div>
      <div class="discountDiv">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the DOM objects and check when you are clicking the same element twice, try this working example:

```js
var previousTarget=null;
$('.jumpDiv').click(function () {
    previousTarget=this;
    if(this===previousTarget) {
        $('.jumpDiv p').remove();
        var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
        var msg = '<p>Your discount is ' + discount + '%</p>';
        $(this).children('.discountDiv').append(msg);
        $(this).children('.discountDiv').slideDown();
    }
    else {
       $('.jumpDiv').children('.discountDiv').slideUp();
    }
    return false;
});
```

```css
.jumpDiv{
    float:left;
}
#main{
    border:1px solid;
    height:500px;
    width:auto;
    background-color: grey;
}
 #main .jumpDiv{
    border-right: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    height:245px;
    width:245px;
    font-size:20px;
}
#main .jumpDiv>div{
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#fee;
    cursor: pointer;
    
}
.discountDiv{
    text-align: center;
    display:none;
    border:1px solid;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<body>
<div id="main">
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jumpDiv">
                <div> Click Here</div>
                <div class="discountDiv">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script
     src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
     integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
     crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to active tab. And then check if that is already open or not.

Here is the `jsFiddle`: https://jsfiddle.net/bf1tmxsw/

Comment: Your code for solving this question should be contained in your answer not just linked to, also answers can have runnable code by using the Stack Snippet button in the editor. As for your actual solution, your example still hides the discount message on a second click which is what OP was trying to prevent.

Comment: Ohh, I thought since it was a practice code. I should be show some better functionality.

Comment: I couldn't get that, why its necessary to add that the answer in snippet. Jsfiddle does the same thing with better code segregation (as I feel). So adding link seems good to me. Although I will keep in consideration of stack snippet and will try to use that in future. :)

Comment: _"why its necessary to add that the answer in snippet"_ It isn't necessary to have it in a snippet, but the code itself should be somewhere in the answer as users shouldn't have to go to some other site in order to see the code. Providing just a link to code could end up having a couple problems. For instance like links rotting. Meaning jsFiddle might one day decide to clear out old fiddles, or just shut down, and then your code would be lost and would not be visible to future users. But it is fine to use a jsfiddle instead of a stack snippet, just be aware of the aforementioned problem

Answer (score 0):

Just check the current event trigger with the following code:

```
$('.jumpDiv').click(function () {
     var discount = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 5);
     var msg = '<p>Your discount is ' + discount + '%</p>';
     $(this).children('.discountDiv').append(msg);

     if($(this).children('.discountDiv').css('display') === 'none'){
         $('.jumpDiv').children('.discountDiv').slideUp();
         $('.jumpDiv p').remove();
         $(this).children('.discountDiv').slideDown();
     }
});
```

Comment: Note OP still wants to change the content of the discountDiv even if it is not hidden: _"discount message div should stay as it is and just update the randomly generated content"_

Answer (score 0):

Made a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kmgy7vz/1/) as easy as possible.

Here you can read more about [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or about [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Now if you need to store the last clicked ID you can use Cookies or the localStorage for that.